# GStreamer element multifilesrc does not throw EOS with stop-index parameter set

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, gst-launch

I have a `pipeline` which does not throw an EOS when I have the `stop-index`parameter set.

The pipeline looks like this:

```
gst-launch-0.10 multifilesrc start-index=140 stop-index=145 location="ADIF%04d.jpg" ! image/jpeg, framerate=5/1 ! decodebin ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=5/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! queue ! x264enc bitrate=5000 ! queue ! h264parse ! avimux ! filesink location=x264enc_1080p_5fps_bitrate_5000.avi
```

This pipeline continuously creates a video of the 5 frames ADIF0140.jpg -> ADIF0145.jpg, repeatedly, until I manually stop it. For example, I would have a video which shows the 5 frames, then the 5 frames again, and again and again etc. Its like its stuck in a loop of some kind.

If I remove the `stop-index`, then the pipeline will generate an EOS when the file list is exhausted. However, I need the pipeline to throw an EOS once I've reached a specific number of frames.

`gst-inspect-0.10 multifilesrc` tells me that the `stop-index` parameter does indeed tell the pipeline to stop once the index has been reached. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Is there a way for multifilesrc to generate an EOS on reaching the `stop-index` parameter?

**EDIT:**

I have followed the suggestion in the comments section and added -e to my gst-launch command. It hasn't made any difference to my output unfortunately. Still don't receive any EOS. However, now when I control c manually, I do see a message printed saying:

```
EOS on shutdown enabled -- Forcing EOS on the pipeline
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
EOS received - stopping pipeline...
```

I ran a `export GST_DEBUG="*:3"` before running the gst-launch command with the `stop-index` parameter set and get an interesting output which I can't make sense of.

```
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:02.708615944  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:02.946719402  1037      0x16b7800 INFO               h264parse gsth264parse.c:1137:gst_h264_parse_update_src_caps:<h264parse0> setting framerate in caps
0:00:02.946788159  1037      0x16b7800 INFO               baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3234:gst_base_parse_set_latency:<h264parse0> min/max latency 0:00:00.200000000, 0:00:00.200000000
0:00:02.946850722  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:03.247947224  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:03.428127717  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:03.671530817  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:03.861473919  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:04.213566287  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:04.400715503  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:04.852917625  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:05.018448277  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:05.200358262  1037      0x16b7800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0x16b78b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:05.266578561  1037      0x16b7800 INFO               h264parse gsth264parse.c:1137:gst_h264_parse_update_src_caps:<h264parse0> setting framerate in caps
0:00:05.266680768  1037      0x16b7800 INFO               baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3234:gst_base_parse_set_latency:<h264parse0> min/max latency 0:00:00.200000000, 0:00:00.200000000
```

If I run the same gst-launch command, without the stop-index, I get an EOS output:

```
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:02.073319330  1052       0xec1400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<avimux0:video_00> Sending event 0xec14b0 (tag) to all internally linked pads
0:00:02.073429953  1052       0xec1400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3554:gst_pad_event_default_dispatch:<h264parse0:sink> Sending event 0xec7e90 (eos) to all internally linked pads
0:00:02.073525245  1052       0xec1400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:606:gst_event_new_new_segment_full: creating newsegment update 0, rate 1.000000, format bytes, start 0, stop -1, position 0
0:00:02.073572978  1052       0xec1400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:606:gst_event_new_new_segment_full: creating newsegment update 0, rate 1.000000, format bytes, start 902654, stop -1, position 902654
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
```

Can anyone help explain these outputs?

Comment: what about adding -e to gst-launch - hope it is there at 0.10 but its just a gues.. it should emit EOS when pipeline is done - its usually used when you shut pipe with ^c